# Docker service not running container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I need help understanding why my dockerfile does not work properly.

I created the image which I called hello-nodemon:

```
FROM node:latest
ENV HOME=/src/jv-agricultor
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/
WORKDIR $HOME/
ADD package* $HOME/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
ADD . $HOME/
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

it works because when I run *docker run -p 3000:3000* it works perfectly. But I want to use docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: hello-nodemon
    deploy:
       replicas: 5
       resources:
         limits:
           cpus: "0.1"
           memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

So i used the commands: *docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml webservice* this return me:

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                  PORTS
y0furo1g22zs        webservice_web      replicated          5/5                 hello-nodemon:latest   *:3000->3000/tcp
```

So *docker service ps y0furo1g22zs* return me:

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                  NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR           PORTS
nbgq8ln188dm        webservice_web.1    hello-nodemon:latest   abner               Running             Running 4 minutes ago
rrxjwudtorsm        webservice_web.2    hello-nodemon:latest   abner               Running             Running 4 minutes ago
7qrz9gtd4fan        webservice_web.3    hello-nodemon:latest   abner               Running             Running 4 minutes ago
lljmj01zlya8        webservice_web.4    hello-nodemon:latest   abner               Running             Running 4 minutes ago
raqw3z0pdxqt        webservice_web.5    hello-nodemon:latest   abner               Running             Running 4 minutes ago
```

My containers

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6daf6afadfdc        hello-nodemon:latest   "npm start"         6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        3000/tcp            webservice_web.1.nbgq8ln188dmz8q8qeb60scbz
2d74f8e9a728        hello-nodemon:latest   "npm start"         6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        3000/tcp            webservice_web.2.rrxjwudtorsm6to56t0srkzda
e3a3a039fdf9        hello-nodemon:latest   "npm start"         6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        3000/tcp            webservice_web.3.7qrz9gtd4fanju4zt6zx3afsf
7f08dbdf0c8d        hello-nodemon:latest   "npm start"         6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        3000/tcp            webservice_web.5.raqw3z0pdxqtvkmkp00bp6tve
c6ce3762d6ae        hello-nodemon:latest   "npm start"         6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        3000/tcp            webservice_web.4.lljmj01zlya89gvmip5z0cf6f
```

**but it does not work**. The browser does not refuse but does not load the page; is infinitely searching.
I do not know what is happening, if someone helps me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with chrome only. I have the same issue in chrome, however, when I open in Firefox it works fine.

Here's how I fixed Chrome:

Looking into this more I think this was either and chrome issue or network issue as I was having the same issue:

Here is how I resolved it:

1. Make sure your `/etc/hosts` file has `127.0.0.1 localhost` (more than likely it's already there)
2. Cleared Cookies and Cached files
3. Cleared host cache

   Go to:`chrome://net-internals/#dns` click Clear Host Cache
4. Restarted chrome
5. Reset Network Adapter
   **Note:** *This was unintentional so not sure if it was part of the fix or not, but wanted to include it in case.*

Unfortunately I'm not sure which step fixed the problem

Comment: you are genius. Thanks a lot.